# How to get Claims for multiple users with AspNetCore.Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

In my .NET 6 application I want to display all users with their claims.

Currently I use the UserManager to get all users like this:

```
var users = await _userManager
      .Users
      .AsNoTracking()
      .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Then I loop through all the users and call `await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user)` to get the claims for each user.

This results in many database requests as a request gets fired for every user. When there are multiple thousand users present it really harms the performance.

Is there a better way to do these kind of bulk operations with AspNetCore.Identity?

Answer (score 0):

if role-related services are enabled and claims are related to roles you can use

```
var users = await _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Role1");
```

otherwise, you will have to create navigational properties manually.

Comment: But then I also have to make multiple requests. One for each role.
How would I create these navigation poperties for claims?

Comment: Also I don't want to modify the the DbContext and use the out-of-the-box solutions of identity instead.